# Transpose data in awk

Tags: awk

I have a benchmarking tool that has an output looking like this:

```
Algorithm       Data Size  CPU Time (ns)
----------------------------------------
bubble_sort     1          16.1
bubble_sort     2          19.1
bubble_sort     4          32.8
bubble_sort     8          74.3
bubble_sort     16         257
bubble_sort     32         997
bubble_sort     64         4225
bubble_sort     128        18925
bubble_sort     256        83565
bubble_sort     512        313589
bubble_sort     1024       1161146
insertion_sort  1          16.1
insertion_sort  2          17.7
insertion_sort  4          26.5
insertion_sort  8          43.7
insertion_sort  16         96.1
insertion_sort  32         263
insertion_sort  64         770
insertion_sort  128        2807
insertion_sort  256        10775
insertion_sort  512        38956
insertion_sort  1024       135419
std_sort        1          17.3
std_sort        2          20.7
std_sort        4          24.4
std_sort        8          32.7
std_sort        16         59.6
std_sort        32         173
std_sort        64         345
std_sort        128        762
std_sort        256        1769
std_sort        512        3982
std_sort        1024       18500
```

And I'm trying to transform this to become more like this:

```
Data Size  bubble_sort  insertion_sort  std_sort
1          16.1         16.1            17.3
2          19.1         17.7            20.7
4          32.8         26.5            24.4
8          74.3         43.7            32.7
16         257          96.1            59.6
32         997          263             173
64         4225         770             345
128        18925        2807            762
256        83565        10775           1769
512        313589       38956           3982
1024       1161146      135419          18500
```

Is there a simple way to achieve this using `awk`? I'm mostly interested in the numbers in the final table, so the header line isn't essential.

==============================

EDIT:

I was actually able to achieve this using the following code

```
{
  map[$1][$2] = $3
}

END {
  for (algo in map) {
    some_algo = algo
    break;
  }

  printf "size "
  for (algo in map) {
    printf "%s ", algo
  }
  print ""

  for (size in map[some_algo]) {
    printf "%s ", size 
    for (algo in map) {
      printf "%s ", map[algo][size]
    }
    printf "\n"
  }
}
```

This works. However, it has two minor problems: It looks a little bit difficult to read, therefore, is there a better and more idiomatic way to do the job? Also, the order of the resulting columns is different from the order in the original data rows. Is there a simple way to fix this order?

Comment: What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is an alternative

```
$ sed 1,2d file | 
  pr -w200 -3t  | 
  awk 'NR==1{print "Data_Size", $1,$4,$7} {print $2,$3,$6,$9}' | 
  column -t


Data_Size  bubble_sort  insertion_sort  std_sort
1          16.1         16.1            17.3
2          19.1         17.7            20.7
4          32.8         26.5            24.4
8          74.3         43.7            32.7
16         257          96.1            59.6
32         997          263             173
64         4225         770             345
128        18925        2807            762
256        83565        10775           1769
512        313589       38956           3982
1024       1161146      135419          18500
```

Comment: That's a beautiful and clean solution, thanks! By the way, does the `-3t` option mean "print 3-column pages"? I cannot find the option in the man page for `pr`. There is only a `-t` option (without a number after the dash) that omits the headers and trailers.

Comment: Oh sorry, I guess I understand now. `-3t` is simply two different options: a combination of `-3` (for 3 columns) and `-t`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Ruby to do this.

Ruby is very much like awk but with additional functions and data structures. The advantage to this is it will correctly deal with missing values by inserting `n/a` if one of the data values is missing.

```
$ sed 1,2d file |
ruby -lane 'BEGIN{
    h=Hash.new {|n,k| n[k]={} }
    l="Data_Size"
}
    h[l][$F[1]]=$F[1]
    h[$F[0]][$F[1]]=$F[2]
END{
    puts h.keys.join("\t")
    h[l]=h[l].sort{|a,b| a[0].to_i<=>b[0].to_i}.to_h
    h[l].each_key { |k|
        a=[]
        h.each_key { |j|
            a.push(h[j][k] || "n/a")
        }
    puts a.join("\t")
    }

}' | column  -t
```

Taking your example and removing the line `bubble_sort     4          32.8` prints:

```
Data_Size  bubble_sort  insertion_sort  std_sort
1          16.1         16.1            17.3
2          19.1         17.7            20.7
4          n/a          26.5            24.4
8          74.3         43.7            32.7
16         257          96.1            59.6
32         997          263             173
64         4225         770             345
128        18925        2807            762
256        83565        10775           1769
512        313589       38956           3982
1024       1161146      135419          18500
```